# use WriteFileAsync to append to file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using a listView to display entries that a user completes and highlighting them based on values entered. After writing a line into the listView, I save the same line of text to a file. Unfortunately, when I write to the file, I overwrite what is already there. I need to either append my newest row to the end of the file, or I will have to write the entire list each time the user adds an entry.

Here's what I have so far with some cases and if statements removed for brevity.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if(tbSystolic.Text != "" && tbDiastolic.Text != "") {
    string bpLevel = "";
    if(Convert.ToInt32(tbSystolic.Text) < 90 || Convert.ToInt32(tbDiastolic.Text) < 60) bpLevel = "Lo";
    //[other if statements removed to save space...]
    string row = tbSystolic.Text+"/"+tbDiastolic.Text+" "+bpLevel+" @ "+tpTime.Time+" on "+dpDate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Content = row;
    //[other stuff done to 'item' removed to save space...]
    lvReadings.Items.Insert(0,item);
    saveReadings(row);
  }
}

async void saveReadings(string row)
{
  StorageFile readingsFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(READINGSFILE, CreationCollisionOptin.OpenIfExists);
  await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(readingsFile,row);
}
```

I suppose that last line is where the actual problem is. I would like to just add the row to the end. If that's not possible, it's fine. I just want to be sure. I don't see any way to open the file that does not require async, and I can't just add "async" to the MainPage : Page.

Comment: @EZI, this is in the context of a App so it does not use the `System.IO.File` class. It is using `Windows.Storage.FileIO`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call [`AppendTextAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701463) instead of `WriteTextAsync`.

```
async void saveReadings(string row)
{
  StorageFile readingsFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(READINGSFILE, CreationCollisionOptin.OpenIfExists);
  await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(readingsFile,row);
}
```

Comment: I see, very different than `File.AppendText` :)